# Scrolling gradient in header using CSS

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to get the header of my website to show a scrolling gradient (imagine the sun rising when scrolling down). Getting  the gradient up is no problem;

```css
#header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #020107 0%, #311B46 50%, #592C67 60%, #803E7E 75%, #CA759C 90%, #EC9D9D 95%, #C35E4D 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```

Getting it scrolling on moving the page however is a problem. I found several guides telling to add;

```
  background-size: 400px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
```

as;

```
    #header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #020107 0%, #311B46 50%, #592C67 60%, #803E7E 75%, #CA759C 90%, #EC9D9D 95%, #C35E4D 100%);
  background-size: 400px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This however gets the header to turn totally dark. What am I missing?

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ - what a proper [mcve] looks like. Please don’t show CSS snippets without any context - right now we can not even know in which _order_ you might have added those properties.

Comment: What is the expected output when user scrolls the page?

Comment: Fair point. I tried to simplify but went to far...  I'll update and take it into account for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate this by applying a background coloration on the body and keep the header transparent:

```css
#header {
  height: 100px;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top: 0;
  border:3px solid green;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
}

body {
  min-height:200vh;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 100px,#fff 100px) fixed,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```